# Enforce good typescript compile-time validation error

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

Typescript language allows perform compile-time validations. Let's walk though following example ([Playground also available](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUHsFsFNQMYwA4BtYA9EoJboLQAuOcohAnsvAgBawIDWANKAGaQBOoOAdgM6EAhjwSwWgjjmQ04xBKEzIOsPnxyQeoAG6DUOACaDCnAFAUqoAHIBXOJIThy0AEaRUfUAF5QAAwAMPqAAPqAA5ACMocFhAExRIaEAzPFhACwpoQCsGQBsGQDsGQAcGQCcoWaU8ADyVBxG6jyOLm4e3mEA1Bn4GcAZAFQV5vAAkjyEsADmsBx8ADwAKgoYEzz6HgKSPJMAfF6gS5ir62FRAPygPLBaM6AAXAfLxx42djgOTq7uoBdLD4crWBrDw%20AAkAG9eKxbgB9ABiOFmhAAMrBCBMOABfCFQ24AJRUhExgQu8MRAlR6NuRyBJ1eM3ezS%20HhMoB%20vghZKRlIx2PBYwm01mcwJAh2xPul2utweVxuHEqFlqMwaGkWT1pG0IW12%20wBzw5kJ40K46FYhAAohglCo1Bo%20cr6sQNEzWnzcVxJJMaJbrcpVI0JSEfAAKHHG25m302gP2iGO1VNT5u8Mm0Ben1WmN2niYgCUgVZbPZCedPDmUaz-pzexCAqmM3mlb9tsaexpwKl8vZcplReLoFLjTmGej1bb0XrQvmo6rrY07cBnd7XAuK-u-YOJjuK8V8Dnsf4iz23n1mtAm14k3ZZ87U8bx5vktvJyHaoWe1%20kvXsulCpMICgAAqsQegUGw1giGWfB7qAIysBaACO1i6PMAAaLAAJosAAgvskEMDwkAAO48CwABC%20wrieoAhseIZ5l4ewvh4aHsuEkoxIxHYnHRH4MUxjw8R4mHsZxjEXHhDzkQA3LBQFrLArC8LA%20iPt48FISh7iLCwK56X%20LAfhqy5-uyCn6EpKlqcZ-wmPZgEAArWM4ejyMM2i6AYiagNMVxyLBIx8AAal5%20jVBwlh-upcEIchqFzAeObzB%20RlpV2Mw7IFIVhRFFlWVcNk0flymFXMmnxTpSWNClOzpQsBnyjsWUAWACyEjBHntQIUXytUDCCOQ%20xBaFejhZF0WhCG4QdFx-TJHsgFTTNc3JLB3WEL1MxwoIeDDTlY0RVtHBzBEHSzaEezFoBu7rYSJXWf1g37aNBh5YppWqad02zXm82XaAS0-atQxVAc90fdZO17RpB1vRwD1lWdF1XWygFINAyB4LARAkPAMwcJwoAAEQjblCOQ4VxP2TT9lAA))

```
// Some complex compile-time type check, for instance, ariphmetic expression validator
type NumericSymbols = `0` | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
type OperationSymbols =  '+' | '-' | '/' | '*'
type Integers<T extends string> = T extends '' ? never : T extends NumericSymbols ? T : T extends `${infer _FirstLetter}${infer Rest}` ? _FirstLetter extends NumericSymbols 
  ? `${_FirstLetter}${Integers<Rest>}` : never : never
type Operation<T extends string> = T extends `${infer leftExpression}${OperationSymbols}${infer rightExpression}` | `(${infer leftExpression}${OperationSymbols}${infer rightExpression})` 
    ? Operation<leftExpression> | Integers<leftExpression> extends never ? never :
      Operation<rightExpression> | Integers<rightExpression> extends never ? never :
    T
:never
type Expressions<T> = T extends string ? T extends Integers<T> ? T : T extends Operation<T> ? T : never : never

// Utility functions
type IfEquals<X, Y, A = unknown, B = never> = (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;
type Undefined<T> = IfEquals<T, never, never, T> extends never ? Undefined<T> : T


// Public type validation genetic
type IsValidOrNever<T> = IfEquals<Expressions<T>, T, T, never>
type IsValidOrUndefined<T> = Undefined<IfEquals<Expressions<T>, T, T, never>>

// Tests
type TestNeverOkay = IsValidOrNever<'(1+2)*3'> // '(1+2)*3'
type TestNeverFail = IsValidOrNever<'1++2'>    // never

type TestUndefinedOkay = IsValidOrUndefined<'(1+2)*3'> // '(1+2)*3'
type TestUndefinedFail = IsValidOrUndefined<'1++2'>    // compile-time error "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite"
```

There is some compile-time validation, in current example it is simple brute-force ariphmetic expression validator, but can be arbitary type expression

Goal is provide export for public generic type, which accepts customer type with validation, and it best, perform some type calculations with good type, and throw pretty compile-time error for bad type

Unfortunately there is only two well-known options: return `never`-like type (`IsValidOrNever`) or call divergent function in haskell-manner like `undefined` (`IsValidOrUndefined`)

These solutions work well, but have own pitfalls: `IsValidOrNever` just returns `never` type, which can be used in circumstances that does not emit compile-time error; and `IsValidOrUndefined` emits strange error for customer (`Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite`)

Question: maybe is there third solution allows emitting pretty and understandable compile-time error for this case? Something like mention instantination of `IsValidOrX` will be applicable

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70203643/prevent-creation-of-type-alias-instance) ? I have user just literal strings for user friendly error messages

Comment: @captain-yossarian Looks good, but works only for literal strings: example above contains literal string only for questing demonstration purposes, but real validation can be arbitary complex :)

Comment: Do you want to get an answer for code which is included in your answer or for your original code? Please provide all use cases. Before passing provided string expression to `Integers` or `Operators` you need to validate it. You need to separate validation logic

Comment: @captain-yossarian There is arbitary generic type `Q<T>` which returns `T` for validated type and `never` for failed type. Goal is having `QQ<T>` which also accepts `T`, and retutrns `T` for good validated type, and causes understable compile-time error for failed type. Implementation of `Q<T>` is absolutely arbiraty. Questing is just about writing wrapper `QQ<T>` over `Q<T>` with usable compile-time error for target library customer

Comment: something like this: `type Parser<T, Result = Validator<T>>=Result extends true ? ComputeExpression<T>:Result` ? Where `type Validator` returns either `true` or user friendly error messaged